# Simulink rejecting data with negative time values when importing from Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

When importing data from workspace with the block `from workspace`, Simulink is rejecting negative time values.
I know you can argue about the sense, but my matrix looks like that.

```
-0,02   0
-0,01   0
0       10
0,01    10
0,02    10
```

In the block I set `Output data type`to double, because I need a 1-D data.
But when looking at the data in Simulink, there are only 10's and no 0's.

Has someone a fix for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either change your data so that the time values are all positive or change the start time of your model to be negative (smaller than or equal to the minimum time value).